# How to identify buttons/text like Submit/Cancel that show up in Dialog Box using Flutter driver java appium?

Tags: flutter, automation, appium-android, flutterdriver

There is a Dialog box that shows up and i want to click Submit/Cancel button in that Dialog using flutter driver in Appium TestNg framework.
The dialog box appears as attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzSTX.png)

```
 public static FlutterFinder find = new FlutterFinder(driver);
    public static FlutterElement createCaseSubmitBtn=find.byValueKey("createCase_btn_submit");
    public static FlutterElement getCreateCaseSubmitBtn() {
        return createCaseSubmitBtn;
    }

CreateCasePage.getCreateCaseSubmitBtn().click();
find.text("Submit").click();//this as well did not work\`
}
```